# Access dynamic nested key in JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, nested-documents

I have an array like `['animals', 'cats', 'cute', 'fast', 'small', ...]`, and want to access nested keys of the object like

```
let object = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: {
        // and so on
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usually I would write `object['animals']['cats']['cute']['fast']['small']..`

The problem is that keys and the number of levels are dynamic (so I can get objects with 2 nested levels or 50), so I have no idea how it can be done

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: which part is known, the key you want to extract from the object, or the structure of the object itself?

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez while writing code - nothing, while script running - everything (how many levels, what key on each level and of course I have access to the object)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate over the array of keys with `.reduce`, where the accumulator is the current nested object:

```js
let object = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: {
        prop: 'val'
      }
    }
  }
};

const props = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'prop'];
const nestedVal = props.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], object);
console.log(nestedVal);
```

To assign a value at the same point, first pop off the last key, use the same `reduce` trick to get to the last object, and assign to the property at the last key with bracket notation:

```js
let object = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: {
        prop: 'val'
      }
    }
  }
};

const props = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'prop'];
const lastKey = props.pop();
const nestedObj = props.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], object);
nestedObj[lastKey] = 'newVal';
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign a value to a nested document like that?

Comment: It's pretty similar, just `.pop()` off the last key first, then use it to assign to the property once you have the nested object